# Cannot Start SQL Developer on Fedora 25

Tags: java, linux, fedora-25

On Fedora 25, I have downloaded jdk-8u111-linux-x64.rpm from Oracle, and installed with rpm -Uvh. After installation, # ls -al /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111
lists a number or directories/files for the installation of JDK. I have also downloaded and installed sqldeveloper-4.1.5.21.78-1.noarch.rpm.

I can start sqldeveloper from my login account, and get the prompt for the pathname of the JDK installation. When I specify /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111, SQL Developer does not start - the Fedora 25 login dialog is displayed instead. File /home//.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf contains entry
    SetJavaHome /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_111

Am I missing some additional configuration requirements for SQL Developer on Fedora 25?

Comment: I cant find an option to edit my original post. File /home/jon/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf contains entry SetJavaHome I mentioned in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I think the issue is that when installing from SQL Developer rpm it stores the JAVA_HOME into /home/user/.sqldeveloper/4.1.5/product.conf and when you upgrade to Fedora 25, the java path changes.
I solved it by running `/usr/local/bin/sqldeveloper`, giving it the correct JAVA_HOME path when asked and after that I could run it normally from the launcher.